# word wrap long character string inside div tag

Tags: php, css

I have a DIV container I'm using as a comment box.  I want to make sure that text doesn't overflow the DIV container, and instead will wrap a long word.  What's the easiest way to do this with CSS and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply the below class to div

```
.break-word {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define `white-space:normal;` as css property to `div` to fit text in box and to break word is `word-wrap:break-word;`